# Unable to create sender/receiver protocols

Tags: swift, generics

I have 2 protocols like this:

```
protocol Receiver {
    associatedtype Input
    
    func send(_ input: Input)
}
protocol Sender {
    associatedtype Output
    
    init<T: Receiver>(_ receiver: T) where T.Input == Output
}
```

To implement `Sender`, I first do this:

```
class TestSender: Sender {
    typealias Output = String
    
    required init<T: Receiver>(_ receiver: T) where T.Input == Output {
        
    }
}
```

However I need to store `receiver` from `init` as a class property. Since `Receiver` has associated type requirements, I have to add a generic type constraint to the entire `TestSender` class, like this:

```
class TestSender<T: Receiver>: Sender where T.Input == String
```

I can then declare a property in `TestSender` like this:

```
private let receiver: T
```

But in the initializer, I can't assign `receiver`.

```
required init<T: Receiver>(_ receiver: T) where T.Input == Output {
    self.receiver = receiver // Cannot assign value of type 'T' to type 'T'
}
```

I tried changing the init method as follows:

```
init(_ receiver: T) {
    self.receiver = receiver
}
```

But now, the Swift compiler says I'm not conforming to the protocol correctly. What is the correct way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

You can make the `Receiver` have an `associatedtype` on the `Sender` protocol, so that a `Sender` is generic over its `Receiver`.

Code:

```
protocol Sender {
    associatedtype InputReceiver: Receiver
    associatedtype Output = InputReceiver.Input

    init(_ receiver: InputReceiver)
}
```

```
class TestSender<T: Receiver>: Sender {
    typealias Output = String

    private let receiver: T

    required init(_ receiver: T) {
        self.receiver = receiver
    }
}
```

---

#### Why didn't the original code work?

With your latest code, you should see the following error:

> Type 'TestSender' does not conform to protocol 'Sender'

This indicates that some requirement is not being satisfied. If you click the fix-it, it shows there is a problem with the initializer. If you click the fix-it again, you get back to the problem of:

> Cannot assign value of type 'T' to type 'T'

This is because you have a generic `T` on `TestSender` **and** also a generic `T` on the initializer. These are different types.

However, ignoring this, the root of the problem is that: in your `Sender` protocol, you only have a generic on the *initializer*, where as in your `TestSender` class you are trying to create a generic over the class itself.

To make a protocol 'generic', you give it an `associatedtype`. And since the `Receiver` is the thing to make generic, that was used to create an `associatedtype`.

Because we have the `Receiver` generic, we can also get the `Output` type in `Sender` as well.

I hope that made sense, ask if you have any questions (it's quite hard to explain!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works well, but I'm curious as to why the original code doesn't?

Comment: The key thing to notice about George's answer is that your mistake was in making `init` itself generic. You can't do that, because the generic placeholder type does not "leak out" of `init` to make `receiver` that type. It is the class TestSender _itself_ that needs to be generic on a Receiver-constrained type.

Comment: @SeedApple I added some more explanation, hope it helps!